# How to query m-to-m relation EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I had two simple entities `Product` and `Category`. Then I wanted to linked them as m-to-m within joining table `ProductCategory`.

Following is the `Product` entity: (`Category` has the same properties)

```cs
public class Product : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    
    public IList<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
```

When I didn't have the relation between `Product` and `Category`, I fetched data (in abstract repository)like this:

```cs
public async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Then I added new method in `ProductRepository`:

```cs
public async Task<IList<Product>> GetProductsCategories()
{
    return await _context.Set<Product>()
        .Include(property => property.ProductCategories)
        .ThenInclude(property => property.Category)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Is it enough to fetch category data for product? (For each product, I want to display its categories)

Comment: Pls fix this - public class Category, Product : Entity at first. It will not be compiled.

Comment: "_Is it enough to fetch category data for product?_" - I'm really confused. Are you expecting a `Yes, it is enough`, or `No, it is not enough`? If you already wrote the code, then why not run it and see what happens - see if it returns the data you need for your display.

Comment: What version EF are you using?

Comment: @Sergey I put both of classes together not to write twice here. Of course, those classes are divided into two cs-files. I dont receive any error, I just recieve in json product without categories.

Comment: @atiyar, as i told before to Sergey i have no problems. I just cant figure out how to display categories in product. I just receive data in json without categories for each products

Comment: "_I just receive data in json without categories for each products_" - don't you think that is something you should have mentioned in your post? If you don't _have_ any problem, or your post doesn't indicate any issue, then what do you expect SO member to do for you?

Comment: @dotnetlooper With your current code, if you are not receiving category data for the products, then edit your post to mention that, so that others can understand what the issue is.